# SQL Server : declare variables inside FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In our project we use dapper for reading from db (.Net orm, but thats not the point). We have prepared wrapper for sql queries which helps pagination and sorting based on parameters passed to web api. The thing this wrapper does is simple add in front of query something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Reviewer, EfficiencyIndicator, AcceptedAt ASC) rn, 
         n.* 
     FROM 
         (...
```

Here goes our queries, depends what we need.

And here's the problem, I have wrote a query and declared some local variables in it.

```
DECLARE @KpiTable TABLE
                  (
                       DocumentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                       ProductName NVARCHAR(250),
                       Vendor NVARCHAR(250)...
                  )
```

Result with wrapper from above:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

So, anyone knows how to wrap subquery in FROM section with variables declaration to achieve something like this?

```
select * 
from
    (declare @variable int = 5

     select @variable
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `DECLARE` is it's own statement, it can't be performed inside another statement. If you want to refercne a variable within a `SELECT` statement, it needs to be declared **before** that statement, and within the same scope and batch.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing with the table, a possible alternative is to use a subquery that presents the same result using `VALUES`. Note that combining this with generic pagination code may be quite detrimental on performance, but that really applies to anything combined with generic pagination code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your pagination logic you need write only one-statements queries. In your case, the query may look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- your queries
) DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES (1, 'test 1', GETUTCDATE())
          ,(2, 'test 2', GETUTCDATE())

) Variables ([ID], [ProductName], [Date])
    -- then some logic here like
WHERE DS.[ID] = Variables.[ID]
```

Then, your pagination query will wrapped this.

It's not efficient. For [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#Offset) you can use `ORDER BY` and `OFFSET`- `FETCH`.